# Adding Google Analytics directly from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I would like to add Google Analytics to my app directly from Android Studio. I go to File > Project Structure > Analytics and select the option to enable Google Analytics. Post which it allows me to select Accounts / Properties / Property ID from my Google Account.

However when I select that and click on OK, nothing seems to happen. I go back to the same option again and it shows me as unselected. What am I missing?

I have the latest version of Studio (1.5.1) with the app's minSdkVersion = 14 and targetSdkVersion = 23.

Comment: maybe you can try invalidate cache first (File > Invalidate Caches / Restart) and then try again?

Comment: it seems that it is a bug with Studio. I installed 2.0 preview and I was able to install Analytics directly from within Studio.

Comment: Update Android Studio to latest stable v2.1.2.